# Install MariaDB 10.2 on Raspbian Stretch

Tags: mysql

How (if at all) can I install MariaDB 10.2 on Raspbian Stretch?
I'm using the November 2017 version of Stretch Lite.

I found some instructions on how to install on Debian 9 (which I realise isn't the same thing) here: https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/#mirror=coreix&distro=Debian&distro_release=stretch--stretch&version=10.2

But they didn't work. I still end up with v10.1.

Does anybody know how I can install 10.2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see [here](https://downloads.mariadb.com/MariaDB/mariadb-10.2.6/repo/debian/dists/stretch/main/), MariaDB's 10.2 builds are only for i386 (32-bit), amd64 (64-bit) and ppc64el (PowerPC). Your Pi has an ARM processor which needs a particular build for that architecture.

Unfortunately, even the Debian sid (unstable) repositories [don't have an ARM build](https://packages.debian.org/sid/mariadb-server-10.2) for 10.2, so you can't use that (though using the unstable repositories is a little risky at the best of times for your system stability).

Since there's no package, you will have to [compile MariaDB from source](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/generic-build-instructions/). Note that compiling large projects from source typically takes a few hours, and there is a chance that it won't work. If you absolutely need MariaDB 10.2, this is what you'll have to do, but you might find it a good idea to look for an alternative option if possible.