# Migrating MariaDB from Stretch to Buster

Tags: pi-4, mariadb

I am currently in the process of migrating my ownCloud from my old Pi 3B to a Pi 4B.
On the 3, I made a backup of my MariaDB with `mysqldump`:

```sh
mysqldump --single-transaction --routines --triggers --all-databases | gzip > backup_db.sql.gz
```

Here is the version info from that file:

```sql
-- MySQL dump 10.16  Distrib 10.1.38-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnueabihf (armv7l)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: 
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   10.1.38-MariaDB-0+deb9u1
```

Now on my Pi 4, I tried to restore this with

```sh
gunzip <backup_db.sql.gz | mysql
```

Unfortunately, this gave the following error:

```
ERROR 1805 (HY000) at line 869: Column count of mysql.proc is wrong. Expected 21, found 20. The table is probably corrupted
```

I realize the mismatching MariaDB versions may be a problem, but I can't install an earlier version on the Pi 4:

```
apt list -a mariadb-server
Listing... Done
mariadb-server/stable,now 1:10.3.17-0+deb10u1 all [installed]
```

According to [Install MariaDB 10.2 on Raspbian Stretch](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/77646/install-mariadb-10-2-on-raspbian-stretch), installing 10.3 on the Pi 3 is probably also not an option.

I also found this in the [MariaDB/mysqldump documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mysqldump/#restoring):

> mysqldump from an earlier MariaDB release cannot be used on MariaDB 10.3 and beyond

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

I resolved my problem by creating a new database dump that only includes the `owncloud` database:

```
mysqldump --single-transaction --routines --triggers owncloud
```

Of course, any additional databases need to be migrated separately.